# Split a string without separators in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, split, powershell-2.0

I want to split a string and store the resulting tokens in variables.

For example, my string is `160519`, and I want to split it in a way where `16`, `05`, and `19` are stored in separate variables.

I tried using `-split`, but because my string doesn't have separators, I'm finding it difficult to cut the string.

Comment: use [substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

You actually can split the string like this if you use a regex.

```
$arr = $string -split "(..)" -ne ""
```

The `.` matches any single character. We then need to filter the array to remove empty values which is where the `-ne ""` comes in (Thanks [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) for the suggestion to replace `| ? {$_}`).

In action:

```
C:\Users\Paarth> $string = "160519"
C:\Users\Paarth> $arr = $string -split "(..)" -ne ""
C:\Users\Paarth> $arr
16
05
19
C:\Users\Paarth>
```

Comment: This is pretty slick.  Why does it produce empty values that need to be removed?

Comment: As per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) empty strings are added where there are adjacent matches. This is really splitting a string *and* extracting some regex, but once we split on this there's nothing left so it works. We remove the empty strings and are left with only the matched entries in the array.

Comment: @JasonBoyd You could technically approach this using regex.match directly and not have to deal with the empty strings but then you have to deal with a slightly more involved regex and groups and whatnot. This is clearer IMO.

Comment: ++; although somewhat obscure, it's a concise solution that has the advantage of working with a variable number of tokens. I suggest reformulating to `$arr = ('160519' -split '(..)') -ne ''`, which is more efficient due to avoiding a pipeline with a cmdlet call.

Comment: @JasonBoyd: Another way of putting it: Adding a _capture group_ (`(...)`) to the regex makes `-split` capture and return the _separators too_; e.g.: `'a.b:c' -split '([.:])'` ->  `@( 'a', '.', 'b', ':', 'c' )`. Here, matches of the separator regex consume the entire string, leaving only _empty_ fields between them, which must be weeded out. In short: it is a clever, but somewhat obscure repurposing of `-split`: a feature that is normally used to capture _separators_ is used to capture _data_ here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the suggestion @mklement0, I've updated the answer with it.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a delimiter, you can't usefully use `-split`. Instead you'll have to use something like:

```powershell
$d = '160519'
$a, $b, $c = $d.SubString(0, 2), $d.SubString(2, 2), $d.SubString(4, 2)

# (That is like doing:
$a = $d.SubString(0, 2)
$b = $d.SubString(2, 2)
$c = $d.SubString(4, 2)
# but doing all three in one go )
```

---

Stop here, this is all you need. :-)

---

Aside: you can index multiple characters out of a string, but they come out as individual characters and each need joining back up into strings again, so it's not neater and not clearer:

```powershell
$d = '160519'
$a, $b, $c = ($d[0..1] -join ''), ($d[2..3] -join ''), ($d[4..5] -join '')
```

[Edit: I guess, if you really care, you can force `-split` to work for you, since you can describe two numbers with a regular expression. The problem with doing that is you normally split based on finding a delimiter, throwing the delimiter away, and keeping the rest. If you want to keep the delimiter you can do it with regex groups, but -split will output empty space where it thinks the content should be, so it takes an ugly workaround to make it work:

```powershell
# split based on a regular expression describing two digits \d\d
# capture the digits in a group (\d\d)
# Filter the output through Where-Object   |?
# Only the numbers will pass, the empty space won't
$a, $b, $c = $d -split '(\d\d)' |? {$_}
```

Or a more standard use of regular expressions with the .Net [Regex] library:

```powershell
$a, $b, $c = [Regex]::Matches($d, '\d\d') | Select -ExpandProperty Value
```

or in PowerShell

```powershell
$d -match '(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)'
$a, $b, $c = $matches[1,2,3]

# hey, this one's pretty nice.
```

]

Comment: split with regex does it, see my answer

Comment: ++; I agree that the last one's pretty nice - perhaps deserves to be featured more prominently.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$text="160519"
$var0, $var1, $var2, $var3= $text -split "(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})"
$var1
$var2
$var3
```