# Write to array every 4 characters

Tags: powershell

I have a string "1111222233334444" with numbers, how to make an array out of it,
"1111", "2222", "3333", "4444".

i want a 4 character instance to be instantiated, how is it implemented in powershell?

Comment: Does this anser your question? [https://stackoverflow.com/a/37129438](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37129438)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string without separators in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129166/split-a-string-without-separators-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple loop would be enough:

```
$s = '1111222233334444'
$i = 0; while ($i -lt ($s.Length-3)/4) { $s.Substring($i*4, 4); $i++; }
```

*(Length-3)/4* is for unaligned blocks of 4. Example: If string is 1111222 it gives *(7-3)/4=1* full items.

---

In addition to comment by Olaf, another way is to use Regex. But, instead of using capturing groups and filtering:

```
$s -split "(....)" -ne ""
```

I would use:

```
[Regex]::Matches($s, "\d{4}").Value
```

Which seems more natural and readable.

Comment: Just out of curiousity: What's wrong with the solution in the linked answer?

Comment: Nothing. There are many solutions to the same problem.